# Is there a way to get a confirmation on deletion from an array list?

Tags: android

This is the removal code that I am using. I am trying to get some validation on it to have maybe a alert dialogue box appear and ask for confirmation?

```
     private void setupListener() {
    listEntries.setOnItemLongClickListener(
            new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapter,
                                               View item, int pos, long id) {
                    // Remove the item within array at position
                    items.remove(pos);
                    entryAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    writeStrings();
                    return true;
                }

            });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this !!!

```
private void setupListener() {
listEntries.setOnItemLongClickListener(
        new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapter,
                                           View item, int pos, long id) {
               AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            context);

        // set title
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Your Title");

        // set dialog message
        alertDialogBuilder
            .setMessage("Click yes to exit!")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                items.remove(pos);
                entryAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                writeStrings();
                }
              })
            .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

            // create alert dialog
            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

            // show it
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    });
                return true;
            }

});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AlertDialog.Builder`, for more information there is a tutorial here http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-alert-dialog-example/